# Nginx: Rewrite sub-directory to different directory

Tags: nginx, apache-2.4, mod-rewrite, rewrite

Currently I have a directory that is down a bit in the codebase, I need to move it to a url that I use on the old server that uses Apache.

In Apache I have:

```
RewriteRule ^ait/(.*) system/ait/$1 [L,QSA]
```

I'm trying to write it in Nginx but can't seem to figure it out, I've tried the below.

```
location /ait/ {
    rewrite ^ait/(.*)$ /system/ait/ last;
}
```

And:

```
location /ait/(.*) {
    rewrite ^/system/ait/$1?$args permanent;
}
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer after much testing.

```
location /ait {
    rewrite ^/ait/(.*) /system/ait/$1 break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don’t need rewrite. Use root:

```
location /ait/ {
    root /path/to/system/;
}
```

Comment: What does `root` do?

Comment: Thanks, I believe this is a better approach than rewrite.